# jquery toggle blur on all textboxes?

Tags: jquery

I have a form which is validated through jquery, but I need the blur event to fire again once the submit button is checked, in case the user deletes anything. It shows an error but the "tick" is still displayed next to the text box, as this only changes on the blur event.

How can I toggle the blur event to all text boxes to re-validate them?

Thanks

edit: added code

```
 if(httpxml.readyState==4)

 { 
  if (httpxml.responseText.indexOf("Successful") >= 0)
 {  
  $("#result").show("slow");
  $("#result").html("Project request has successfully been sent");
  $("#result").removeClass("result_error");
}
else if (httpxml.responseText.indexOf("Fail") >= 0)
{
 $("#result").html("One or more errors have occured, please fix and submit again");
 $("#result").addClass("result_error");
 $("#result").show("slow");
 $(':text').trigger('blur'); <<--- Blur text boxes here 
}   

}
```

checking:

```
   function check_email(email)
{
    var httpRequest;
         make_request()


    $("#loading").show(); 

    function stateck() 
    {
        if(httpxml.readyState==4)
        {
            if (httpxml.responseText.indexOf ("Email Ok") >= 0)
        {

            $("#email_tick").show();
            $("#email_cross").hide();
            $("#email_error").hide("normal");   
            $("#loading").hide();
            emailok = true;


        }

         else 
        {               
            $("#email_tick").hide();
            $("#email_cross").show();
            document.getElementById('email_error').innerhtml = "Invalid email";
            $("#email_error").show("slow");
            $("#loading").hide();
            emailok = false;

        }
        checkCanSubmit();           
        }
    }

httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
email_url="../checking/check_email.php?email=" + email.value;
httpxml.open("GET",email_url,true);
httpxml.send(null);
}
```

Comment: if you're using the the validate() plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) then as soon as a user does anything to a field after the initial validation, the field is revalidated.

Comment: Hi, I am using my own ajax validation, thanks.

Comment: So what happens in the blur handler? And out of curiosity if youre already using jQ why arent you using $.ajax()?

Comment: I havent got round to added $.ajax the blur handler checks the textbox with an external php file using regex, its a long file I can add if you like?

Comment: i dont need the php so much... just the js for blur callback function... like does it add/change/remove a class name, set an attribute, etc.. Im trying to figure out what youre trying to do markup/visual-wise when you blur an element.

Comment: I have added how I check email...this is the same for each textbox so there is no point adding everything :)

Comment: Simply calling `$(':input').blur();` OR `$(':input').trigger('blur');` should work without any wrangling. Are you getting any errors in your js error console?

Comment: Nope no errors, I have tried it on the button submit and still neither work, thanks.

Comment: So what ended up being the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not really clear on what youre asking but if you are asking how to trigger the blur manually:

```
$(':text').trigger('blur');
```

Comment: can you post the relevant parts of your JS and html? I think we may all be misunderstanding what it is you need to do. It will be easier to figure out if we can see what we are dealing with :-)

Comment: i saw that :-) seem my on your initial question above.

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger it by:

```
$('input:text').blur();
// or
$('input:text').trigger('blur');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('input').blur();
});
```

The code reads as:

When the button with `id="button"` is clicked, find all `<input />` and  fire the `blur` event on them.

Tune the selectors to match your needs.

Comment: Thanks this doesnt seem to work, I am using $('input').blur(); but its not actually on the button click, it checks if a response text is fail. I have a div showing the error this works fine, blur just doesnt work.